# Is there a function to select the current source code block in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to write a function that pretty-prints the current source code block into a PDF. I know I can use ps-print-region-with-faces, but it would require that I first select the source code block.

Is there a function in org to do this selection?

thank you in advance

Edit:

the answer is org-babel-mark-block (answered by bertfred in a comment)

org-mark-element selects the block but also selects the BEGIN_ END_ markers.

Comment: `org-babel-mark-block` ?

Comment: @bertfred can you post an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike `org-mark-element`, the function `org-babel-mark-block` only selects the contents of a block.

Answer (score 5):

`org-mark-element` should be able to do the right thing. It's bound to <kbd>M-h</kbd> by default.

Comment: Unfortunately this selects also the headers of the block (#BEGIN_SRC, #END_SRC)

Comment: Yeah, `org-babel-mark-block` (from a comment above) selects only the contents, which is also what I came here looking for.