# How to set the mark using keybindings when C-SPC is unavailable to emacs

Tags: spacemacs

Suppose I have the following code block in an org file.

```
#+begin_src sql
SELECT id
FROM product
WHERE name = 'Apple'
#+end_src
```

I want to select this part:

```
SELECT id
FROM product
WHERE name = 'Apple'
```

I was taught to use `C-SPC`, but `C-SPC` was already used by my OS, is there any way to do this? For example, bind this function to another shortcut? By the way, I'm using spacemacs.

Comment: Your question is about how to set the mark if C-SPC is hijacked before emacs can use it. Isn't strictly related to org-mode, neither about how to bind keys, although that will solve your problem. Please update tags and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebind `set-mark-command` to anything (<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> in the example)

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'set-mark-command)
```

or

```lisp
(define-key 'global-map (kbd "C-.") 'set-mark-command)
```

Alernatively, without having to rebind anything:

- it's also bound to <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd>.
- You can exchange point and mark <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> -- *if you're not using the current mark already it'll be the same*.
- You can mark the paragrah, or org-element with <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>, move the point to first line you want, then reduce region exchanging point and mark first, and moving the point again to the desired end. Sounds far more complicated than it is, but sometimes it's faster than any other method.

Sure there are more ways, but I do use those.

---

Straight to the example, to select directly only the src block contents you can use `org-babel-mark-block` which is bound to <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>. Sure not really the most friendly shortcut for the memory muscle.

Thanks to bertfred for pointing it in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51908/11477)